# How to get current week number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time

How should i do to get the current week number in javascript. Here are some ways i've tried:

```
var week = new Date().week;
var week = new Date("W");
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: There is no such function. What do you want the week to be relative to?

Comment: What do you mean by relative?